# optim vector-matrix multiply with eigen lib

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen3

exist way how to optimalize this multiply vector by matrix? note matrix A is symmetric column major) temp is Vector:

```
    approx = (temp.transpose() *A).normalized();// MAtice je symmmetricka hermitovska! je jedna jak nasobim> lepsi perofrmance!!!§

}
```

And this : 
PowerEvec is vector and largestEvalue is Scalar.....

```
    DATA=DATA-largestEvalue*PowerEvec*PowerEvec.transpose();
```

I try

```
     noalias()
```

method but without improve....

Comment: Make sure you compiled with compiler optimization ON and SSE. Also, what is the matrix size? Scalar type?  What is the current speed?

Comment: matrix is square :size is 1000*1000 to 5000 * 5000 time is 1e-2. Scalar type all double

Comment: approx.noalias() = (A*temp).normalized();

Comment: Does it make it sense?

Comment: For a 5k^2 matrix, 0.01s makes sense. For a 1k^2 matrix, you should rather get 1ms. If you want faster performance then try to leverage matrix-matrix products instead of matrix-vector products.